# Splitting arithmetric expressions in python with regexps

Tags: python, regex, parsing

i have a following snippet, generally i want to split arithmetic expression (with negative numbers) to tokens.

```
import re
import collections

NUM     = r'(?P<NUM>-?\d+)'
PLUS    = r'(?P<PLUS>\+)'
MINUS   = r'(?P<MINUS>-)'
TIMES   = r'(?P<TIMES>\*)'
DIVIDE  = r'(?P<DIVIDE>/)'
LPAREN  = r'(?P<LPAREN>\()'
RPAREN  = r'(?P<RPAREN>\))'
WS      = r'(?P<WS>\s+)'

Token = collections.namedtuple('Token', ['type', 'value'])

def generate_tokens(text):

    pattern = re.compile('|'.join((NUM, PLUS, MINUS, TIMES, DIVIDE, LPAREN, RPAREN, WS)))

    scanner = pattern.scanner(text)
    for m in iter(scanner.match, None):
        token = Token(m.lastgroup, m.group())

        if token.type != 'WS':
            yield token

expr = "2-2"
out = [token for token in generate_tokens(expr)]
for token in out:
    print(token)
```

And there is problem with splitting negative numbers with this code, output is

```
Token(type='NUM', value='2')
Token(type='NUM', value='-2')
```

But should be

```
Token(type='NUM', value='2')
Token(type='MINUS', value='-')
Token(type='NUM', value='2')
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Try putting your NUM group after the MINUS group so that the pattern matches the minus sign first

Comment: @PhuNgo But then negative numbers not matching.

Comment: Add a check (e.g. `(?!^)`) to make sure that an expression does not start with operators

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is just to create expressions by seperating each part with space.

ex.

```
expr= '2 - -2' 
Token(type='NUM', value='2')
Token(type='MINUS', value='-')
Token(type='NUM', value='-2')
```

The problem is that the computer dosen't know wheter you've forgot to add a minus sign in "2-2" expression or if you wanted to substract 2 - 2, which would be 0. I think it shouldn't be a problem to just specific the way how the input should be given.